# Include PHP script in all cPanel accounts?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, webserver, cpanel

Is it possible to include a PHP script to all cPanel accounts in a server without the script residing in each user's home directory?

For example `global.php` resides somewhere in the server:

```
// global.php
class global
{

}
```

Now `user-a.com/test.php` and `user-b.com/test.php` (separate cPanel accounts) will have `new global();` available to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `global.php` in a directory in `include_path` (or create a new one) and all PHP scripts on the server will have access to it via `include('global.php')`. I would recommend against auto-including it though.

Comment: So any user must type `include('global.php')` first? If ever how to auto include it (I know your against but just so we know)?

Comment: `auto_prepend_file` will do so, but it can be overridden.